# How to reroute http requests to another server in node

Tags: node.js, http, azure, forwarding

I have a mobile app that relies on a node.js server hosted on a Microsoft Azure VM. I am currently in the process of creating a new Azure VM that I would like all API directed towards but since I have already released the app on Google Play, users that have already downloaded the app will have code that directs all API calls to the old VM. I would like to add logic to the old VM's server code that reroutes all incoming HTTP requests to go to the new VM and return to the client the response from the new VM even though they are directly sending a request to the old VM server. Essentially, the old VM would act as a middle man. Does anybody know how to do this using Node?

Comment: Was the IP address of the old VM hardcoded into the app? If it was just a domain name, it would just be trivial to update the A record. Otherwise, you could also use a reverse proxy such as Nginx (not necessarily using Node).

Comment: @yjwong The problem is that users that have not updated the app will have code pointed towards the old VM server which we are trying to phase out. New users will be pointed to the new/correct server.

Answer (score 0):

As @yjwong's comment said, if you have an independent domain name to service the old app and bind the hostname of old Azure VM as a CNAME record in DNS, you can change the CNAME record to bind the hostname of new Azure VM to point users using the old app to the new/correct server.

About the CNAME record, please see the Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record.

Otherwise, you can install and use the reverse proxy like Nginx to redirect & rewrite the urls accessed by the old app to the urls of the new/correct server.

Here are some steps below as reference to help doing it.

1. Install Nginx on the old Azure VM，and enable the module `ngx_http_proxy_module`.
2. Configure Nginx as a reverse proxy to redirect the urls from the old app accessing, please refer to the doc of the module `ngx_http_proxy_module` http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html or search some related articles with the keywords `nginx`, `reverse proxy`, `redirect`, etc.
3. Stop the nodejs server on the old Azure VM, and configure the Nginx port as the nodejs port to service the old app.
4. Restart nginx and test the old app for redirecting.

Note that for the step 2 above, please make sure the two Azure VM (old & new) on the  same Azure VNet and use the static private IP address (internal) for the new Azure VM, because the one Azure VM can not be allowed to directly access the public address of the other Azure VM. So you need to set up the remote address of the new/correct server using the private ip address in the reverse proxy.

You can refer to these docs below to set up Azure Virtual Network for the two Azure VMs.

1. Create a Virtual Network on Azure new portal: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-vnet-arm-pportal/
2. How to add a static private IP address to an existing VM: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-static-private-ip-arm-pportal/#how-to-add-a-static-private-ip-address-to-an-existing-vm
3. If the two Azure VM existed not belong to any VNet, you need to move them into a VNet Subnet without losing your virtual hard disk, please refer to the two docs http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karldb/archive/2013/12/13/moving-an-existing-virtual-machine-into-a-virtual-network-subnet-without-losing-your-virtual-hard-disk-or-your-mind.aspx and http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/06/17/step-by-step-move-a-vm-to-a-different-vnet-on-azure.aspx.